# CMake on CUDA and C++ project

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, cuda

I have project that's structured in this way:

```
- root
 - commons (C++)
 - cpu (C++)
 - gpu (CUDA C++)
 - CMakeLists.txt
```

In each of these commons/cpu/gpu directories I have src and test directory, with corresponding CMakeLists.txt.

I didn't set any flags in CMake files - it's just adding several subdirectories which build executables.

Root CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(root LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

include(CTest)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

add_subdirectory(commons)
add_subdirectory(cpu)
add_subdirectory(cuda)
```

root/cpu/tests CMakeLists

```
project(CPU_TEST)

add_executable(cpu_tests cpu_test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(cpu_tests cpu_impl ${Boost_LIBRARIES} commons)

add_test(NAME all_cpu_tests COMMAND cpu_test)
```

For GPU tests it's equivalent but file is gpu_test.cu and cpu names are replaced with gpu.
Tests are done with Boost Unit Test Framework. 
Problem: When I try to build cpu tests with CMake I got following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cpu_tests.dir/cpu_test.cpp.o: in function `boost::basic_wrap_stringstream<char>::basic_wrap_stringstream()':
>   /usr/include/boost/test/utils/wrap_stringstream.hpp:40: undefined reference to`std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream, std::allocator >::basic_ostringstream()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

All my files in commons and cpu are with .cpp extension, in gpu - .cu.
GPU tests are building fine, even if I create the same test as in CPU.
When I changed cpu_test extension to .cu it worked.

- Should every of my file be with .cu extension, even if it's pure C++ code?
- If not, why CMake cannot compile .cpp test files, when .cu are compiling?

Comment: What version of C++ compiler are you using? Do you set the `CXX_STANDARD` somewhere in your CMake project?

Comment: I'm using g++ (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1) 9.3.0 on Manjaro.

I didn't set my CXX standard explicite.

Comment: You might try doing that in your top-level CMake, see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html).

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work.